# Why does Internet Explorer go offline when my dial up connection is offline, even if I am connected to wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-explorer, internet-connection, dial-up

Whenever I open Internet Explorer I get this error : "The webpage is unavailable because you are offline". I have to disable Work Offline mode every time. It only started doing this after I added a dial up connection. But the dial up connection only works when my phone is plugged in, most of the time I use a wifi connection. Why does IE go offline when the dial up connection is offline, even if my wireless connection is online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this in the past when the Internet Explorer - Internet Options are set to `Always dial my default connection`.

Go to Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections Tab. In the middle you will see your dial up connection with options below it. Choose to `Dial whenever a network connection is not present`. Click `OK`.

Right now the last option is probably set, which makes it think it has to dial up but can't find a dial tone.

[image]

*Note: this image has them greyed out because I don't have a dial up connection.*